# Retrieving Rails Model Column Names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When one retrieves a Rails model object, how are the column (or object attribute) names accessed?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
User.column_names
```

Like a lot of things in Rails, it just works :)

Answer (score 6):

Example:

```
user = User.find(1)
p user.attributes.keys
```

Comment: This of course requires there be at least one record in the table

Comment: The OP asked "When one **retrieves** a Rails model object..."

Comment: We should have one record with id equal 1. Too many conditions for a simple operation.